# Ansible: How can I Include variable file with conditional statement

Tags: ansible

I have three sets of servers. Depending on the hostname, I want the client to grab the correct file. I tested the playbook on a server with the word "batch" but it picks up both files `group_vars/perl` and `group_vars/batch`

```
pre_tasks:
  - include_vars: group_vars/web
    when: "'web' in ansible_hostname"
  - include_vars: group_vars/batch
    when: "'web' not in ansible_hostname"
  - include_vars: group_vars/perl
    when: "'web' not in ansible_hostname" or "'batch' not in ansible_hostname"
```

Answer (score 2):

Ansible will handle group_vars for you. For any hosts in the group `web`, the vars at `group_vars/web` (or `group_vars/web.yml`) will be automatically included. See [Splitting Out Host and Group Specific Data](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_inventory.html#splitting-out-host-and-group-specific-data) in the Ansible docs.

To answer your question about conditional variable includes, the examples you gave are the correct syntax. Here's another example, not using group_vars:

```
- include_vars: vars/{{ ansible_distribution}}_packages.yml
  when: install_extra_packages is defined and
        install_extra_packages != ''
```

Note that `include_vars` accepts expressions, so you can use variables to determine the vars files to pull in dynamically.

Comment: I'm running this locally w/o ansible inventory or else I would leave it to Ansible to handle.

Comment: If you're not using groups, don't use `group_vars/`. Place your vars files in `vars/` and pull them in from there. The real answer here, though, is to use groups—otherwise you're spending time reimplementing a solution Ansible already provides.